# When are Completed tasks removed from Kanban board

Tags: tasks

Out of the box, i can view Task object records in Kanban board, where my tasks can be marked 'Completed' by dragging them over.

When are they going to be removed from this board?

**Update** So it seems that the 'kanban board' is a form of display for individual lists. So if you want to not see 'completed' tasks, you switch to 'Open tasks' list (or apply a filter). Additionally, when the task is dragged to 'Completed' it's `IsClosed` property is updated to `true` and that can be also used as a filter.

This is somewhat counter-intuitive, because when you go to 'All Tasks', you still see all completed tasks, so i will keep the question open as it may well be i am doing something wrong.